# Detect text changed in textbox mvvm windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8

How do I detect changes when text is typed in a textbox in a windows phone 8 application when using mvvm but note that I'm not using mvvmlight.

I've tried using interaction.Triggers and while the event is triggered every time I type some text, the model that's binded to the control does not set the Text property of the control in my viewmodel.

My viewModel has a property that's allowing to access the actual Model and normally I'd have:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Person.Title, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

but to test, I've just created a Title property directly in my ViewModel but same behaviour.

I'm pretty sure the Text property is binded correctly as I've put breakpoints when my view gets initialized and it does get called.

Here is the code I have and triggers an event every time I type, but unfortunately, my Title never seems to get set.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TitleTextChanged, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Update:**

The property changed is definitely raised from my ViewModel using

```
public string Title
{
    get { return this._title; }
    set { if (this._title != value) this.SetProperty(ref this._title, value); }
}
```

but as mentioned originally, I only added this property to test the property change event as I normally would access my model object through my ViewModel this way:

```
public PersonModel CurrentPerson
{
    get { return this._currentPerson; }
    set { if (this._currentPerson != value) this.SetProperty(ref this._currentPerson, value);}
}
```

I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you remembered to set the interface, such that it can understand the notifyproperty changed? as setting INotifypropertyChanged I think its called

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextInViewModel, Mode=TwoWay, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas ... Are you raising the property changed? mvvm-light helps you do this, and without that, you need to manually do that.

You could post the code for your property, but I'll venture a guess that that's the issue.

Also, you say you bind the view to the model which changes the viewmodel ... and it all sounds like a soup ... You view binds to the view model. you view model is acting as a bridge between your model, and your view (shouldn't know about your view ofcourse, but it facilitates you what you need from the model).

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope this clarifies things a bit!

Comment: I think you might be onto something as I've not removed my interaction.triggers, and even when I click on a button, I can see that my PersonViewModel is not correct, so I must have something messed up somewhere, but I can't see what. I'll update when I find out what it is!

Comment: Ok, let us know. Also, why is your title saying MVVM-Light when you specifically say in the question you're not using mvvm-light?

Comment: My bad about the "with" MVVMLight. It was meant to be without!! That's what happened when you work through the night until 7am :(.. It's definitely an mvvm issue, so I'll leave this post opened so I can post a reply, but I'll post another question in a bit as I'm definitely confused with the mvvm part! Sorry if I wasted your time!

Answer (score 0):

To detect changes when text is typed in a textbox i use Behavior from Prism.

In xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}">
      <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <extensions:UpdateTextBindingOnPropertyChanged />
      </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Behavior code (UpdateTextBindingOnPropertyChangedBehavior.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace MyApp.Extensions
{
/// <summary>
/// Custom behavior that updates the source of a binding on a text box as the text changes.
/// </summary>
public class UpdateTextBindingOnPropertyChanged : Behavior<TextBox>
{
  private BindingExpression _expression;

  /// <summary>
  /// Called after the behavior is attached to an AssociatedObject.
  /// </summary>
  /// <remarks>
  /// Override this to hook up functionality to the AssociatedObject.
  /// </remarks>
  protected override void OnAttached()
  {
    base.OnAttached();
    _expression = AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    AssociatedObject.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(this.OnTextChanged);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Called when the behavior is being detached from its AssociatedObject, but before it has actually occurred.
  /// </summary>
  /// <remarks>
  /// Override this to unhook functionality from the AssociatedObject.
  /// </remarks>
  protected override void OnDetaching()
  {
    base.OnDetaching();
    AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= new TextChangedEventHandler(this.OnTextChanged);
    _expression = (BindingExpression) null;
  }

  private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    _expression.UpdateSource();
  }
}
}
```

You will need to add System.Windows.Interactivity.dll to the project. This Behavior will call binded property setter each time when controls TextChanged event fires. Works great (if you do not froget to set Mode=TwoWay).